# CPPUTestMakeFile Help linking

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to make a makefile, which can make an exe for CppUTest.  It can not find the headers, what have I done wrong?  First time making a makefile, not 100% sure what I'm doing.

```make
#The compiler to use
CC = g++
LINK = -g -pedantic -Wall -lstdc++ -lpthread -ldl -lm -Wl,-rpath,.
COMPILE = -g -O3 -D_THREAD_SAFE -pedantic -Wall -c -Wno-deprecated 
#Name of the EXE file to create.
EXE    = ./Tests
SRCS   = $(shell ls *.cpp)
OBJS   = $(subst .cpp,.o,$(SRCS))
#Extra flags to give to the C compiler.
CFLAGS = 
#Libraries to include
LIBS= -lCppUTestExt -lCppUTest -lm 
#Extra flags to give to the C++ compiler. 
CXXFLAGS = -I/home/mg/DS-5-Workspace/Tests/include       
#Extra flags to give to compilers when they are supposed to invoke the linker, ‘ld’, 
#such as -L. Libraries (-lfoo) should be added to the LDLIBS variable   
#instead.            

LDFLAGS = -L/home/mg/DS-5-Workspace/Tests/cpputest/lib
#Extra flags to give to the C preprocessor and programs that use it (the C and  
#Fortran     compilers). 

CPPFLAGS = 

.SUFFIXES: .o .cpp

.cpp.o:
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(COMPILE) $(LIBS) $<

all: $(OBJS)
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(OBJS) -o $(EXE) $(LINK)


-include depend.mak


depend:
g++ -MM $(SRCS) > depend.mak


#static:
#ar -crvs $(a) $(OBJS)


#shared: $(OBJS)
#$(CC) -shared -Wl,-soname -lc -o $(so) $(OBJS) 

clean:
rm -rf $(OBJS) depend.mak $(EXE) $(so) $(a)
```

I have the following error:

> error: CppUTest/CommandLineTestRunner.h: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're mixing up a lot of things.

Let's clean this up and keep only what is needed :

```make
EXE      := Tests
SRC_DIR  := .
OBJ_DIR  := obj
SRC      := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJ      := $(SRC:$(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)

CPPFLAGS := -I/home/mg/DS-5-Workspace/Tests/include
CPPFLAGS += -MMD -MP -D_THREAD_SAFE

CXXFLAGS := -W -Wall -Wno-deprecated -pedantic -O3 -g

LDFLAGS  := -L/home/mg/DS-5-Workspace/Tests/cpputest/lib
LDFLAGS  += -Wl,-rpath,.

LDLIBS   := -lCppUTestExt -lCppUTest -lm -lstdc++ -lpthread -ldl

.PHONY: all clean fclean re

all: $(EXE)

clean:
    $(RM) -f -r $(OBJ_DIR)

fclean: clean
    $(RM) -f $(EXE)

re: fclean all

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

# %.a:  $(OBJ)
#   $(AR) crvs $@ $^
#   ranlib $@

# %.so: CXXFLAGS += -fPIC
# %.so: $(OBJ)
#   $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR):
    @mkdir -p $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp | $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

-include $(OBJ:.o=.d)
```

Some explanations :

- Avoid the `$(shell ...)` function, because it'll be executed each time the variable is called if assigned with the `=` operator instead of `:=` operator.
- `$(CC)` is a built-in variable containing `cc` or `gcc` (should be equivalent). Use the built-in `$(CXX)` to use `g++`.
- `-g`, `-pedantic`, `-O3`, `-Wno-deprecated` and `-Wall` are compiler flags, they should be in the `CFLAGS` (for C) or `CXXFLAGS` (for C++) built-in variables.
- `-I <path>` and `-D_THREAD_SAFE` are preprocessor flag, thus should be in the `CPPFLAGS` built-in variable.
- `-MMD -MP` will auto-generate dependency files (`.d` extension) for each `.o` file. You can [read more here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html).
- `.cpp.o:` is a suffix rule, and [suffix rules are the old-fashioned way of defining implicit rules for make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Suffix-Rules). You should just rely upon these implicit rules make already know about or make your own the modern way.
- You don't need to define `.SUFFIXES:` by yourself for such widely used targets. *The variable SUFFIXES is defined to the default list of suffixes before make reads any makefiles.* Make 3.82 defines these suffixes by default :

  ```make
  .SUFFIXES: .out .a .ln .o .c .cc .C .cpp .p .f .F .m .r .y .l .ym .yl .s .S .mod .sym .def .h .info .dvi .tex .texinfo .texi .txinfo .w .ch .web .sh .elc .el
  ```

If you have any questions, go on.

Comment: Wow, thanks, this helps.  As you can tell, this is my first makefile.  I still have the error  "undefined reference to `CommandLineTestRunner::RunAllTests(int, char**)'"  It now finds the header but can't run the code.

Comment: Well, now this is not a makefile error anymore. Are all your .cpp files in the same directory as the Makefile ?

Comment: All of my .cpp files are in the same directory.  Do I need to put the CppUTest files there too?  I will mark the answer as correct anyhow, I guess too not a makefile error. Thanks.

Comment: The linker is telling you that it can't find the implementation for the function `CommandLineTestRunner::RunAllTests(int, char**)`. I don't know if it is part of the CppUTest files or your project instead, so you should post a whole new question if you can't solve that problem.

Comment: The error seems to be that the code cannot find those .o files?  So something wrong with that make file.

Comment: I use this kind of Makefile daily for my C/C++ projects, I can assure you there's no problem here. Can you edit your question and post the full output of the compilation process ?